# How to determine big O of something that looks like this: (x -1) + (x - 2) + (x - 3) ... (x - x)

Tags: java, performance

I'm trying to brush up on my big o calculations. If I have function that shifts all of the items to the right of 'i' 2 spaces I have a formula that looks something like:

```
(n -1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3) ... (n - n)
```

Where the first iteration I have to move (x-1) items, the second (x-2) items, and so on...
the method:

```
int[] s = {1,2,3,4, , }

public static char[] moveStringDownTwoSpaces(char[] s){
    for(int j = 0; j < s.length; j++){

    for(int i = s.length-3; i > j; i--){
        s[i+2] = s[i];
    }
    return s;
    }
}
```

I know this is O(n^2), but I don't quite understand the math behind transforming this:

```
(n -1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3) ... (n - n)
```

into this

```
O(n^2)
```

In my mind if n = 5 (String is of length 5), I would have...

```
(5-1) + (5-2) + (5-3) + (5-4) + (5-5) = 5(5 - ???)
```

which is

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + (n-4) + (n-5) = n(n - ???)
```

so that gives me 5*5 = 25 which is n^2. but what is the ??? I don't know what to put for the variables in the formula. I don't even know if I'm even going by this the correct way. AKA I forgot how to do math :(

Comment: [Sum of an arithmetic sequence.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

Comment: Do you realise your `return s;` appears inside the outer loop?

Comment: oops sorry about that. it should be after outer loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(n -1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3) ... (n - n)
```

Just rewrite the following as:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ....+ (n-1)
```

which is equal to: `(n(n+1)/2 - n)`.

Now you can see it is `O(n^2)`.

As noted by @hvd you may want to put the `return` statement outside the loop.

Comment: Note: `1 + 2 + 3 +...+ (n - 1) = n(n-1)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

The Big-O notation is not the exact upper bound. It's an asymptotic upper bound. In many cases where a algorithm may look like O(n^2), but amortized analysis may show a linear order complexity.